# send selected item as parameter to method in view-model [WPF,Caliburn]

Tags: wpf, listbox, caliburn.micro

I have this problem. I use caliburn micro in WPF. In view I have listbox, and I bind on event MouseDoubleClick method in view-model. I would like send as parameter selected listbox item. But I don’t know how do it.

in view I have this:

```
    <ListBox Name="Friends" 
             SelectedItem="Key"
             Style="{DynamicResource friendsListStyle}"
             Grid.Row="2" 
             Margin="4,4,4,4"

             Micro:Message.Attach="[MouseDoubleClick]=[Action SendRp(Key)]"

             PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp"
             PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" 
             MouseRightButtonDown="FriendsListBoxMouseRightButtonDown"/>
```

In view model I have this method:

```
    public void SendRp(string key)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(key);
    }
```

Any advance, thank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont know much about caliburn but my guess is you have to write

```
Micro:Message.Attach="[MouseDoubleClick]=[Action SendRp(Friends.SelectedItem)]"
```

also you should either omit the `SelectedItem="Key"` or use a binding to your ViewModel like this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Key}"
```

Comment: Ok, but your solution doesn’t work, same I try first then I wrote this question.

Comment: ok, i saw i made a mistake, please try with Micro:Message.Attach="[MouseDoubleClick]=[Action SendRp(Friends.SelectedItem)]"

Comment: You can use `SendRp($this)` since CM sets `SelectedItem` as `$this` for `ListBox` .

Comment: Yes, @xmedeko's answer is right. I checked his answer on my result.