# Send menu item name as parameter to view-model method [WPF, Caliburn.Micro]

Tags: wpf, menu, caliburn.micro

Hi I bind  event PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown on view-model method, I would like send as parameter menu item name.

in view I have this:

```
    <MenuItem Name="Online"
                          Header="Online"
                          Micro:Message.Attach="
[PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown]=[Action ChangeStatus(Name)]">
```

So in thi case I would like send Name =>("Online") as string to method:

view-model:

```
    public void ChangeStatus(string status)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(status);
    }
```

Any advance?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450042/send-selected-item-as-parameter-to-method-in-view-model-wpf-caliburn

Comment: I think it isn’t duplicate, so try this. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar problem as in [this message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450042/send-selected-item-as-parameter-to-method-in-view-model-wpf-caliburn), you have to write

```
[PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown]=[Action ChangeStatus(Online.Name)]
```